# How to find unique values in a datetime array only based on date (ignoring time)?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have the following datetime array and want to find the unique values in my array BUT only based on date (ignoring the time). Can anyone explain how to do this? I tried to use the unique function but it obviously takes the time into account as well. How can I tell matlab to ignore the time?

```
A = {'04-Feb-2016 15:09:56';'05-Feb-2016 15:14:14';'07-Feb-2016 20:05:50';'07-Feb-2016 23:13:20';'10-Feb-2016 15:09:56'};

A=datetime(A);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options. You could convert to a date string (using only year, month, day) and then compare those.

```
dates = datestr(A, 'yyyymmdd');
[~, inds] = unique(dates, 'rows', 'stable');
uniqueDates = A(inds);
```

The other options is to create an array of the `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` properties.

```
data = [A.Year, A.Month, A.Day];
[~, inds] = unique(data, 'rows', 'stable');
uniqueDates = A(inds);
```